# iPhone4 Simulator in XCode 4.0.2

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator, iphone-4

Sorry, this is going to be a dumb question.

How do I run my app on iPhone4 simulator using Xcode 4.0.2?  (I want to test the high-resolution image issues).

My drop-down doesn't seem to include this device: http://cl.ly/9dya

And Mr Google doesn't seem to be coughing up the usual.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you open the iOS Simulator, on the Menu Bar under Hardware -> Device there should be an option for iPhone (Retina) which will show the Retina Device Simulator

[image: Menubar]

Answer (score 1):

The retina-/iPhone 4 screen is a setting in the simulator itself.